# Xamarin access child view property from parent

Tags: c#, xamarin

So i have a view that contains a list of views that display in a carousel. I want to have the code behind of parent take action when a particular property in one of the child view changes.

Parent:

```
<CarouselView x:Name="EventWizardCarouselView" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Grid.Row="0">       
    <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentView Content="{Binding .}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
</CarouselView>
```

The item source for this view is set in code behind like following:

```
_views = new List<ContentView>() {
    new EventBasicInfoView(),
    new EventRulesView(),
    new EventLocationsView()
};
EventWizardCarouselView.ItemsSource = _views;
```

Child view contains property that parent cares about:

```
<Picker x:Name="EventTypePicker" ItemsSource="{Binding EventTypes}" SelectedItem="{Binding EventType.Value}">
```

I want to do same as following in parent but can't due to access violation. Is there some way to make the picker (EventTypePicker) public or something so that i can do following?

```
EventTypePicker.SelectedIndexChanged += EventPickerIndexChanged;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind `Picker` [SelectedIndex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.picker.selectedindex?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_Picker_SelectedIndex) and evaluate the value from model class, this should give you access to other model class property and easily to change other property

Comment: This has nothing to do with view model. I want to all this with code behind.

Comment: what is the use of making view as item source (not just use basic model class and view model) if you can use item templating?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you're following a proper MVVM pattern, with the ViewModels being a separate class, rather than in the code behind for the View.

I would recommend that the The ViewModel for the parent contains an `ObservableCollection` of child ViewModels. The child ViewModel raises an event and your parent ViewModel handles that event.

Comment: I am using mvvm pattern however this is a view only issue so view model doesn't care about this. I want the code behind in the parent to be able to access the picker. I was able to do this with some ugly implementation of picker.parent.parent.parent...